# Error in using STR_TO_DATE() along with a placeholder

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Here's the query I'm trying to use:

```
sql= """SELECT APPT_NBR, STR_TO_DATE(APPT_SCHD_ARVL_TS,'%M/%D/%Y')AS Schd,
                         STR_TO_DATE(APPT_ACTL_ARVL_TS,'%M/%D/%Y) AS actl,
        DEST_LOC_NBR, CARRIER_TYP_NBR,
        VND_NBR, VND_NBR_SUPPLIER, APPT_TYP_NBR, APPT_NBR_OF_CNTRS
        FROM mixeddata            
        WHERE DEST_LOC_NBR= (%s)"""

c.execute(sql, loc_nbr)
```

It keeps throwing this error:

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyMySQL3-0.5-py3.5.egg/pymysql/cursors.py", line 105, in execute
    query = query % escaped_args
ValueError: unsupported format character 'M' (0x4d) at index 95
```

The error does not come in when I'm not using a place holder for DEST_LOC_NBR, for eg. if I simply put DEST_LOC_NBR=3950 the query will work just fine. But I want to use a variable in that location for my code.

Answer (score 3):

The `%` characters in the `'%M/%D/%Y'` format are interpreted at the Python level, where the [string formatting operation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) then complains there is no `M` format (it would do the same for `%D` and `%Y`).

Double the `%` to escape them (single `%` characters will be sent to the database):

```
'%%M/%%D/%%Y'
```

The full string definition would then be

```
sql= """SELECT APPT_NBR, STR_TO_DATE(APPT_SCHD_ARVL_TS,'%%M/%%D/%%Y')AS Schd,
                         STR_TO_DATE(APPT_ACTL_ARVL_TS,'%%M/%%D/%%Y) AS actl,
        DEST_LOC_NBR, CARRIER_TYP_NBR,
        VND_NBR, VND_NBR_SUPPLIER, APPT_TYP_NBR, APPT_NBR_OF_CNTRS
        FROM mixeddata            
        WHERE DEST_LOC_NBR= (%s)"""
```